# Apex Code: Distinguish Package Patch Org vs Package Major Org somehow

Tags: apex, managed-package, patch

Is there any way to figure out at Apex code level whether org we are currently connected to is a Patch org or a Major Package org?
Basically we need a way to distinguish programmatically between these two.

We've already tried calling System.requestVersion(), but unfortunately patch() method on a Version object always returns null.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share with us the reason? We may be able to help you better

Comment: How about `[SELECT OrganizationType FROM Organization]` ?